# Extract a part of a text from XML file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, replace

I'm trying to extract a part of the text inside a node from the following XML file. I manage to delete the part before but not the one after. 
I'm doing a text comparison that border the part to extract. 
However nothing is displayed on the page. I searched online and used different methods without success like :

```
     `var reg = new RegExp(/If/gi);`
     `.replaceData( reg , "");`
```

Or :

```
     `y = y.replace(/If..../gi,"");`
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
            <Header>
                <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
                 <MerchantIdentifier></MerchantIdentifier>
                    </Header>
                    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                            <Result>
                              <MessageID>15</MessageID>
                              <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                              <ResultMessageCode>8541</ResultMessageCode>
                              <ResultDescription>The SKU data .... Amazon catalog: brand (Merchant: &apos;Stor&apos; / Amazon: &apos;Winnie the Pooh&apos;). 
                               **Part I want to delete =>** If this is the right ASIN for your product, update your data to match what&apos;s in the 
                                Amazon catalog. If it&apos;s not the right ASIN, make sure that your data for standard_product_id is 
                                correct. 
                                </ResultDescription>
                                <AdditionalInfo>
                                    <SKU>30604</SKU>
                                </AdditionalInfo>
                            </Result>
                            <Result>
                              <MessageID>17</MessageID>
                              <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                              <ResultMessageCode>8541</ResultMessageCode>
                              <ResultDescription>The SKU data .... Amazon catalog:  part_number (Merchant: &apos;&apos; / Amazon: &apos;ST-30614&apos;). 
                               **Part I want to delete =>**If this is the right ASIN for your product, update your data to match what&apos;s in the 
                               Amazon catalog. If it&apos;s not the right ASIN, make sure that your data for 
                                standard_product_id is correct. 
                                </ResultDescription>
                                <AdditionalInfo>
                                    <SKU>30614</SKU>
                                </AdditionalInfo>
                            </Result>
```

HTML & JavaScript :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
//getting XML File
xhttp.open("GET", "/projectv1/raport", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

    //Parse specific node 
    var result = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ResultDescription")[0].childNodes[0];

    //delete the first part of the text => The SKU data .... Amazon catalog:
    var a = result.replaceData(0,220, "");

    //trying to delete the second part with a text comparison because the part to extract is variable
    var a = result.replace("This ......","");


    var fin = document.getElementById("demo2");
    fin.innerHTML = a; 


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `substring` and `indexOf` methods ?

example for your problem:

```
var a = result.substring(34, result.indexOf("If"))
```

Documentation:
[String.prototype.substring() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [String.prototype.indexOf() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: After your message I learned about these two methods. However, for some reason, it does not work... I had to break down both methods for it to work
But by learning about these methods I found a simpler method (in my opinion):     
 > split () and I use this for my code :

`var att = res.split('catalog:').pop().split('. If').shift();`